# Multithreading in Rails: while loop is blocking another method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, deadlock, puma

I am using Puma server to achieve multithreading. Here is my controller:

```
class PhoneCallsController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live
  protect_from_forgery :except => :record_call

  # GET: Return messages to JavaScript pop-up
  def get_messages
      random_num = rand(65536)
      log "Start of get_messages, random id = #{random_num}"
      sleep 60
      #while session[:new_record_date]==session[:prev_record_date] do
      #  sleep 1
      #end
      session[:prev_record_date] = session[:new_record_date]
      render :status => :ok, :json => ['my message']
      log "End of get_messages, random id = #{random_num}"
  end

  # POST: Record a phone call. Called by PBX.
  def record_call
    log 'Start of record_call'

    data = Hash.from_xml(request.raw_post)
    pbx_data = data['PbxData']

    pc = PhoneCall.new({
                            :command => pbx_data['cmd'].strip,
                            :recipient_ip => pbx_data['RecipientIP'].strip,
                            :phone_num => pbx_data['PhoneNum'].strip
                        })
    pc.save!

    session[:new_record_date] = pc.created_at

    debug_text = "call received:\ncmd: #{pc.command}\nRecipientIP: #{pc.recipient_ip}\nPhoneNum: #{pc.phone_num}"

    log debug_text
    render :status => :ok, :text => debug_text

    log 'End of record_call'
  end

  # Test page to simulate PBX calls
  def call_test
  end

  # Test page to receive pop-up notifications
  def messages_test
  end

  private
  def log(msg)
    Rails.logger.info msg
    puts msg
  end
end
```

So, there are two main methods: `get_messages` is called by JavaScript and its task is **not** to return a result until phone call arrives (connection should be hold).

Second method - `record_call` is called by PBX script when a call is being answered.

The problem is - when only

```
sleep 60
```

is mentioned in `get_messages` then `record_call` method can be called at any time and the whole allpication isn't being locked.

But if I replace this `sleep 60` with

```
while session[:new_record_date]==session[:prev_record_date] do
  sleep 1
end
```

(as it should be) - this `while` loop blocks entire application.

What am I doing wrong? Why `sleep` doesn't block the application, but when it is wrapped into `while` loop (suppose it is an infinite loop) the application is being locked?

I suppose that the multithreading in my case isn't a true multithreading and `sleep` is treated in a special way.